# Writting a memory stress test in javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, memory, memory-management

over these past years I was absolutely convinced (in javascript, also it should apply to any other language) that it was better, memory wise, to declare a variable and reuse it later, instead of creating a new variable every time you call a function. So now trying to win an argument I decided to write a test for this, one reuses an object (test2) and the other creates a new one upon invocation(test1):

```
var tmp = {x: 0};
var i = 0;
function test1(a){
  return {x: a+1};
}
function test2(a){
  tmp.x = a+1;
  return tmp;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    for(i=0; i< 10000000; i++)
        test1(i); // or test2(i)
}
animate();
```

But after testing the above code, I'm getting the exact same result in the memory profiler. I've even tried using performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize (enabling the chrome flags for it to work) but I don't see any difference. So my guess is that either I'm not testing this correctly or the chrome compiler is doing some weird optimizations that avoids allocating memory in the test1.

Is there a way to know if I'm properly testing this?

Comment: If you think about it, one of the most intensive areas of optimization in a modern JavaScript runtime would be the creation of new objects. Don't try to out-guess the runtime engineers; focus on algorithmic efficiency, because they can't help you with that.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm working in the context of webgl applications so I try to avoid memory allocation as much as possible to avoid sutterings caused by the gc releasing memory

Comment: You have no way of knowing whether updating properties on existing objects is more or less efficient than creating new objects. As you've discovered, the runtime is very good at what it does.